# Can Rust consume an iterator passed into a function?

Tags: iterator, rust, move-semantics, ownership-semantics

I'm trying to implement a simple REPL calculator in Rust and I'm hitting brick walls all over the place.

I'm consuming chars while iterating over a hardcoded string. When I hit a numeric character I want to pass control over to a function that will consume the rest of the number (assuming the number has more than one digit) and return the number, converted to an Integer.

I'm having trouble with passing `Chars` iterator to a function. The error I'm getting is `use of moved value: 'iter'`.

I understand that I can't mutate something that I gave to someone else - something that had its ownership moved - but I don't know any other way of doing this, especially since the Chars iterator is non-copyable.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Token {
    Addition,
    Substraction,
    Multiplication,
    Division,
    Integer(i32),
    Error,
}

fn consume_number(mut iter: std::str::Chars) -> Option<i32> {
    while let Some(item) = iter.next() {
        println!("{:?}", item);
    }

    return Some(1337);
}

fn tokenize(line: &str) -> Vec<Token> {
    let mut iter = line.chars();
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();
    let mut token;

    while let Some(c) = iter.next() {
        if c.is_whitespace() { continue };

        if c.is_digit(10) {
            token = match consume_number(iter) {
                Some(i32) => Token::Integer(i32),
                None => Token::Error,
            };
        } else {
            token = match c {
                '+'                    => Token::Addition,
                '-'                    => Token::Substraction,
                '*'                    => Token::Multiplication,
                '/'                    => Token::Division,
                _                      => Token::Error,
            };
        };
        tokens.push(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}



fn main() {
    let line = "631 * 32 + 212 - 15 / 89";
    println!("{:?}", tokenize(&line));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes, it's done in the `FromIterator` trait.

What you experience here is much more basic:

```
fn consume_number(mut iter: std::str::Chars) -> Option<i32> { ... }

while let Some(c) = iter.next() {
    ...
    match_consume_number(iter)
    ...
}
```

When calling `match_consume_number` you are transferring ownership of the iterator to it. It means that at the next iteration of the loop body, this `iter` variable is no longer available.

If the iterator is meant to still be usable afterward, you should pass a reference to it:

```
fn consume_number(iter: &mut std::str::Chars) -> Option<i32> { ... }

while let Some(c) = iter.next() {
    ...
    match_consume_number(&mut iter)
    ...
}
```

You were close!

Comment: Thank you very very much kind sir!

Comment: BTW how did you know that the problem was that the iter was going out of scope in the while loop? What gave it away? What should I have been looking for?

Comment: `use of moved value: 'iter'.` means that the ownership of `iter` was transferred to something else. "move" in Rust means "transfer ownership". You'll get used to it ;)

Comment: @neektza: The `iter` didn't "go out of scope", though, that's a different notion. When you try to use an identifier that's "out of scope", you get an "unresolved name" error. That's not what happened here!